# im trying to add a header section to my profile page using swift (Xcode) with out using the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is what i have done so far but it keeps giving me the error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter with identifier ProfileHeader - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'**

how would i fix this?

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
private let headerIdentifier = "ProfileHeader"

class UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

// MARK: Properties
var USER_NAME: String = "Username"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: headerIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.navigationItem.title = "Profile"

    self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.collectionView!.register(ProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)
    fetchUsersData()

}

// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    //Declare header
    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileHeader
    return header
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell

    return cell
}


// MARK - API

func fetchUsersData() {

    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    print("Current user id is \(currentUser)")


    Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(currentUser).child(USER_NAME).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else {return}
        self.navigationItem.title = username
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewForSupplementary` is called for both header and footer view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileHeader
            return header
        }
        else {
            fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
        }
    }
```

And if you don't want `viewForSupplementaryElement` to be called for footer set

```
extension UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                          layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                          referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

Also Please remove

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: headerIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

This is registering a `ProfileHeader` as cell and in next statement you register ProfileHeader as section header also `self.collectionView!.register(ProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)`

**EDIT 2:**

As OP is facing difficulty fun understanding solution, I am writing whole class below

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
private let headerIdentifier = "ProfileHeader"

class UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    // MARK: Properties
    var USER_NAME: String = "Username"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: headerIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.navigationItem.title = "Profile"

        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.collectionView!.register(ProfileHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)
        fetchUsersData()

    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize.zero
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader {
            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProfileHeader
            return header
        }
        else {
            fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        // Configure the cell

        return cell
    }


    // MARK - API

    func fetchUsersData() {

        guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        print("Current user id is \(currentUser)")


        Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(currentUser).child(USER_NAME).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else {return}
            self.navigationItem.title = username
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want me to replace my collectionView with the one you provided above? if i do that it it gives me "Fatal error: Unexpected element kind:"

Comment: @gino-sesia: Not entire collection view just `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method and also add `referenceSizeForFooterInSection`

Comment: okay this doesn't make sense to me. Sorry im new to this, so i am not exactly sure as to what you want me to do

Comment: @gino-sesia: In your code simply replace `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` with my `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` and add `extension UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {`

Comment: below your class definition. Simply copy `extension UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewDelegate {` from my answer

Comment: im getting this now:  Redundant conformance of 'UserProfileVC' to protocol 'UICollectionViewDelegate'

Comment: @gino-sesia: That means you already have `extension UserProfileVC: UICollectionViewDelegate` somewhere in your file, for now simply write `extension UserProfileVC {`

Comment: its no longer giving me errors now but its no longer changing color when i set the background color of the profile page or even the background header

Comment: @gino-sesia: Hey you already had `referenceSizeForFooterInSection` in your code you wrote it two times?

Comment: @gino-sesia: I am writing entire file, simply copy whole file as is and run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214932/discussion-between-sandeep-bhandari-and-gino-sesia).